# Is it possible to find an element by its value in Eclipse Expressions view?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

**Find Dialog** allows to search for specific elements but by name only

Comment: Question is incomplete..Add more details. Users are answering based on the hints and guesses.

Answer (score 0):

If the expression that you are looking for is that:

```
String var = "some text";
```

You could make a search like this:

[image]

but if the assignment is dynamically there are not way to find that.

Answer (score 0):

I think conditional breakpoint is your answer.
[Conditional Breakpoints in Eclipse | vogella blog](http://blog.vogella.com/2008/07/14/conditional-breakpoints-in-eclipse/)
[How do I set a conditional breakpoint?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint?)